# I would like to declare a variable from user input

Tags: variables, excel, naming, vba

I would like to create an infinite while loop

```
do while endOfLoop<>"" OR endOfLoop <> "end"
    If endOfLoop = "" Then
        Answer = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to quit? If you are done press cancel _
            and then type in 'end'")
        If Answer = 6 Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

    'request from user to enter a column name

    Dim ColumnName & count
    count = count + 1
```

Keep in mind I just wrote this code now, in this box, so I don't know if everything else is correct besides the "dim rowname&count"

But a you can see, what I would like to do is have an infinite while loop until the user enters "end" or cancels out Where with each iteration count increases and I declare variables:

```
ColumnName1
ColumnName2
ColumnName3
...
ColumnName(x)
```

Is this possible?

EDIT:

For anyone who wishes to use this code, This is meant to Activate from Cell to Cell and read in the headings into an array. For example if you are in Cells(1,1) and you have headings First | Last | Middle

Then it will create an array of "ColumnNames" to do so until there are no more Filled in Columns. As a shout out to DCRomley, I just want to explain that when there is no text in the cell column of the active Cell, the while loop will stop, so unless you have infinite cells filled in, using this can't end in an infinite loop. Thanks to everyone who helped me create this solution! Also, in the case that someone can help me re-word this so that I don't have to add the "count = count-1" clause at the end, that would be wonderful.

```
Do While endOfLoop <> ""
    ReDim Preserve ColumnNames(Count)
    ColumnNames(Count) = endOfLoop
    Count = Count + 1
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
    endOfLoop = ActiveCell.Text
Loop
Count = Count - 1
```

Comment: I would suggest `Dictionary` object

Comment: explain? or perhaps if you have a good reference to how to use dictionary object could you link me?

Meanwhile I just realized, could I just make an infinite array and instead of ColumnName(x) I could just reference with ColumnName(x)? Would that be a smarter move?

Comment: Use an array to store the user input - you can resize it as needed using `ReDim Preserve`

Comment: -1 because of obvious unchecked code: `Answer = MsgBox(..` and `Dim ColumnName & count`. And `do while endOfLoop<>"" OR endOfLoop <> "end"` will be an unintentionally infinite loop.

Comment: I explained in my code up there that it was written on the spot and I wasn't finished writing it. I appreciate the help, but I'm a bit offended that you gave me a negative rating because of it, even though I'm still in the middle of building the code. Was that really necessary? I can only write one question an hour already, and I don't see that changing anytime soon when you do stuff like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want the `Count = Count - 1` at the end, you could simply change your code to the following:

```
Dim Count As Integer
Dim ColumnNames()

Count = 0
Do While endOfLoop <> ""
    Count = Count + 1
    ReDim Preserve ColumnNames(Count)
    ColumnNames(Count) = endOfLoop
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
    endOfLoop = ActiveCell.Text
Loop
```

This will make sure that the count is correct at the end. However, it might be even cleaner to do something like this (which does not require the selecting of cells)

```
Sub makeList()
Dim thisRow
Dim headerNames()
Dim listOfNames As String
Dim cc As Integer
cc = 0
Set thisRow = Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlToRight))

For Each c In thisRow
  If c.Value = "" Then Exit For
  cc = cc + 1
  ReDim Preserve headerNames(cc)
  headerNames(cc - 1) = c.Value
  If cc = 1 Then listOfNames = c.Value Else listOfNames = listOfNames & ", " & c.Value
Next c
MsgBox "there were " & cc & " cells." & vbCrLf & "Their names were " & listOfNames

End Sub
```

Note - the above will work even if there is only one cell in the range - although `thisRow` will end up pointing past the end of the headers, the `Exit For` will still stop the loop after one iteration.

Comment: I apologize for cryptic "short variables names" `c` and `cc` - `cell` and `cell counter` respectively. A bad habit from being a Very Old Programmer - there were computers on which I had only 2 characters for all my variable names, since there was only 4k of RAM... some old habits die hard.

Comment: So my end goal program is to copy a bunch of columns after reading them in from a central file, and re-distribute the columns into a new sheet in the proper order. I'm going to have intelligent design in it so it adds the column if that column doesn't exist and does some other things, but meanwhile, will everything up until "If cc = 1 Then listOfNames etc...," mean that each column is copied into a block of the array?

Comment: Right now all that is copied is the name of the header. No copying of data in the column is being done. That would look quite different - especially if you want to change the order. A word of advice: this site works best if each individual question gets its own post, rather than editing a question "as the problem evolves" - so that the questions / answers are easier to find for others, and may be more relevant. You can always post a link from the old to the new, and vice versa "This is a continuation of [link]" and "For the rest of the story, see [link]".

Comment: Ah, so don't make edits to add in my solutions? Meanwhile the copying part is another code I've started on myself and am continuing to work on. One question I'm wondering is how do you declare c as Cell? I can't find a .cell object

Comment: No - you can show your solution when you find it. But if your original question was "how do I capture the headings in a set of variables", then don't change it (as you looked like you were about to do...) to "how do I copy and re-arrange columns". You must not try to declare `c` as a `cell` (it would be `Range` not `cell`, by the way) - it has to be a Variant. Otherwise you cannot use it in a `For Each` style loop.

Comment: Oh, yeah, I'm only going to ask that question if I need help, I was just telling you to give you context to help you answer if this code would work for me. I'm teaching myself VB, is there anything wrong with not declaring a variable at first?

Comment: Declaring variables before using them is good practice, in my opinion. Use `Option Explicit` at the head of your module to force this - it will complain if there is an undeclared variable, which incidentally is a great way to find typos (e.g. you declare `number` and use `nubmer`.) VBA is a good language to learn - but documentation sucks and the object model changes from one version to the next. Good luck - and don't hesitate to come back and ask good questions. Do put yourself in the shoes of people answering - the better you formulate the question the more likely you will get good answers.